# select next/previous 10 rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have  a `list` that displays only 10 rows.

I need to select the next 10 and previous 10 rows.

However, the ID I use as reference are not exactly in order.

e.g:

```
 1,2,5,10,15
```

How do I select the next few rows using the ID?

Answer (score 38):

you can try limit:

```
select * from `table` limit <startIndex>,<NumberOfRecords>;
```

example:-

```
select * from `user` limit 5,10;
```

This will return 10 rows starting from 6th row.

Comment: is the startindex the ID?  what do i use for reference?

Comment: thanks, how do I get the startindex(row number)?  sorry, still new in mysql.

Comment: @tep: If you have sequential Id's in column then give id as rowNumber.

Comment: how do i get the ID of the 10th row, so that when the user clicks next again, the next 10 rows will show again.

Comment: @tep: you have to save it somewhere in your code. or you can use `SELECT id FROM table limit 9,1;` or find some implementation for rownum in mysql.

Comment: hi harry. im trying this query to get the id. "select MIN(blog_id) from mytable where id<'$id' order by id DESC limit 10";  however, it doesn't seem to show any results. what can you suggest? thanks. :)

Comment: @tep: there is no error in your query. may be you don't have any data whose id is less then `$id`. Check your id and database. First try to execute query in database for your id and see the results.

Comment: @tep: you are always welcome. Don't forgot to upvote/accept useful answers.

Answer (score 3):

a possible query would be

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id > current_id LIMIT 10
```

for the 10 previous

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id < current_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: hi, im using a query similar to this.  however, how do I update the ID so that when the user clicks next again, the next 10 rows will display again.

Comment: this one is best with ajax ;)

Comment: Aren't you relying on the id to be always fetched sequentially for this to work?   Granted it should be, but there is always the possibility that a row has been deleted so the next 10 ids would not necessarily be the next 10 numbers.  without the logic to know what id you ended with the previous run you could end up with duplicate results.

Answer (score 2):

First select 10 first value:

```
SELECT * FROM `leave_type` ORDER BY id asc limit 10;
```

and then

```
select * from `leave_type` limit 10, 10;
```

will show rows after 10th value(range of 10) and start with 11th.

Answer (score 1):

```
(
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   id < $myid
ORDER BY
        id DESC
LIMIT 10
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   id >= $myid
ORDER BY
        id
LIMIT 10
)
ORDER BY
        id
```

Comment: im using a query similar to this. however, the problem i'm having is with the id.  some rows are being displayed repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **limit** keyword of MySQL.